# Converting javascript array into individual variables using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to explode an array into individual variables which I can then post to my PHP file using `$.ajax`.

My array is as follows:

```
var arr = ["11th", "february", "2013"]

// How can I go through this array and take each element and place it into its individual variable?
```

Comment: What does the resulting object look like?

Comment: You ca directly used your array for posting data. What is the purpose of doing this ? WHat should be the name of each var ?

Comment: I would like to separate the array into individual variables so that I don't have to do it on the server side when I use the values to query a table. Variables are called, `day`, `month`, `year`. I know its odd to do this but I have no other option. Thanks.

Comment: Yes but when you will do your post in ajax, you can send different var and so, send separatelly arr[0], arr[1] and arr[2]. You can do this by writting this in the configuration of your ajax post: `...,data { day: arr[0], month: arr[1], year: arr[2] }...`

Comment: @user1073122 Wow thats great, I did not know that was possible. I have honestly tried to research that exact functionality online and could not find any information on it. Thanks again, I am going to give it a try!

Comment: @DanielMakinbo: All the information you need is in your Javascript book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use your array for posting data

when you do your post in ajax, you can send different var and so, send separately arr[0], arr[1] and arr[2]. You can do this by writting this in the configuration of your ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
    ..your config..,
    data: { 
        day: arr[0], 
        month: arr[1], 
        year: arr[2] 
    },
    ...your config...
});
```